# Как получить время нажатия кнопки?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

есть страница, на которой есть date(...), но время всегда загружается при загрузке страницы, а нужно, что бы загружалось после нажатия определённой кнопки, как это правильно сделать?

Comment: javascript onclick, если локальное время браузера? ajax, если через php

Comment: @splash58, через пыху могут быть небольшие проблемы с точностью секундах.

Comment: @doox911 могут, но локальное время может быть вообще от балды, а стоит ли задача того, что какой-нить   сервер времени поднимать. Я думаю, что для обычных задач вполне сгодится

Comment: "есть date(...)", а нельзя ли полностью выражение указать? непонятно, что за время (устанавливаете определенное значение?) и для чего оно нужно.